# How to simulate a kind of maxlength for any datatype C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to verify the maxlength of a text with method that returns bool.

```
public bool ExceedsMaxLength(object value)
{
     if(this.MyPropertyType == typeof(String))
     {
           return ((string)value).Length > this.MaximumAllowed;
     }
     //Numeric?????
}
```

I was trying to do this inside this method

```
if(this.MyPropertyType == typeof(Int16))
{
     return ((short)value > Int16.MaxValue);
}
```

Am I in the correct way? This is ok and I should do this for any numeric data type? OR there is another simplified way  to do this with a special method from .NET?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of information is 'MaxLength' supposed to return from a numeric type?

Comment: At first, it was planned to control the string values but if you can see the parameter is an object, so I want to simulate that could pass any data type and return true or false if the size is bigger than the size allowed. In string I have a property MaximumAllowed just for string and this must match with the column size of a database table. In other types it should not be greater than its type

Comment: Your code reading `return ((short)value > Int16.MaxValue);` will always return false because when you explicitly cast to a `short`, a lossy conversion takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned you are only interested in capping the maximum length based on the string representation, the following code will do what you need:

```
public bool IsOverMaximumLength(object value)
{
    return (value.ToString().Length > this.MaximumAllowed);
}
```

If you want to check lengths for numerous data types, more methods or overloads are more appropriate:

```
public bool IsOverMaximumLengthForInt32(long value)
{
    return value > Int32.MaxValue;
}

public bool IsOverMaximumLengthForInt16(int value)
{
    return value > Int16.MaxValue;
}
```

This is a reflection approach and it may also suit your needs:

```
public static bool ExceedsMaximumValue(object source, object destination)
{
    Type sourceType = source.GetType();
    FieldInfo sourceMaxValue = sourceType.GetField("MaxValue");

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sourceMaxValue, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The source object type does not have a MaxValue field associated with it.");
    }

    Type destinationType = destination.GetType();
    FieldInfo destinationMaxValue = destinationType.GetField("MaxValue");

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(destinationMaxValue, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The destination object type does not have a MaxValue field associated with it.");
    }

    object convertedSource;
    if (destinationType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType))
    {
        convertedSource = source;
    }
    else
    {
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(sourceType);
        if (converter.CanConvertTo(destinationType))
        {
            try
            {
                convertedSource = converter.ConvertTo(source, destinationType);
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The source object type cannot be converted to the destination object type.");
        }
    }

    Type convertedSourceType = convertedSource.GetType();

    Type[] comparisonMethodParameterTypes = new Type[1]
    {
        destinationType
    };

    MethodInfo comparisonMethod = convertedSourceType.GetMethod("CompareTo", comparisonMethodParameterTypes);
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(comparisonMethod, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The source object type does not have a CompareTo method.");
    }

    object[] comparisonMethodParameters = new object[1]
    {
        destination
    };

    int comparisonResult = (int)comparisonMethod.Invoke(convertedSource, comparisonMethodParameters);

    if (comparisonResult > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to do a fix to my string type as you stated but I want to control others data types. That's my question. Regards

Comment: I recommend using overloads or simply more methods to complement your `ExceedsMaxLength` method. I will edit my post to show you.

Comment: `IsOverMaximumLengthForInt16` may as well just read `return true`.  There is no `int` value greater than `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for pointing that out, it was in fact an error. It has been corrected and another sample was added.